# DNS server config restored after reboot

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-4

I add new hostname to the /etc/resolve.conf but it reset after I reboot Raspberry pi.

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

OS is raspbian buster on raspberry pi 4.

Edit: I have to change my dns server because it has problems on the local network.

Comment: Did you add the hostname to the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?

Comment: No i just set new hostname on the resolv.conf and don't know why it happen.

Comment: This is normal Linux operation. Why do you think you have to change it?

Comment: @Milliways My dns server has problems on the local network and i have to change dns server.

Comment: DO NOT add detail in Comments; edit your question. "My dns server has problems on the local network" is meaningless. People will suggest solutions, but unless you clarify the problem may just waste your time. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
[How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)

Comment: `# Generated by resolvconf` essentially means "don't edit this file by hand".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't manually update the `resolv.conf`, because all changes will be overwritten by data that your local DHCP server provides. Therefore, the network manager of Raspbian Buster has configured by `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Every configuration of this config file always is overwriting to other network config files on the OS.

All you need is that you should config your network by `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` as you want. In this case, follow this procedure:

```
nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

Then, add this line:

```
static domain_name_servers=4.2.2.4 8.8.8.8
```

---

Before Raspbian Strech (I'm not sure enough), you could do that. It's some difference we have here and you must follow them to configure the network.

Comment: Thank you I set and save the file but it not solved.

Comment: Ah yes. i reboot raspberry its worked.